# Javascript self executing functions and variable scope

Tags: javascript, scope, self-executing-function

Could someone explain to me this behavior?

```
var obj = function()
{
    var _bar = 10;
    function i_bar(){return ++_bar;}

    return {
        bar  : _bar,
        i_bar: i_bar
    }
}();

obj.bar     // prints 10, OK
obj.i_bar() // prints 11, OK
obj.bar = 0 // prints 0,  OK
obj.i_bar() // prints 12, NOK
```

Since the only variable is `_bar`, shouldn't the last `obj.i_bar()` have printed `1` instead of `12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bar` is not the same references as what `i_bar` is referencing.  Value types are not by reference, so you are copying `bar` into the return object, but it is not the `bar` that your function is referring to.  Try this:

```
var obj = function()
{
    var self = this;

    function i_bar(){return ++self.bar;}

    self.bar = 10;
    self.i_bar = i_bar;

    return self;
}();
```

Comment: Because value types are not passed by reference.  Functions and objects are passed by reference.  When you construct a new object, you are making a copy of `bar`, but it is not the same `bar` that the function is referring to.

Comment: You are correct, and initializing `bar` as an object fixes it. But what actually confused me was this: I simply declared the variable but didn't assign any value to it. After that I did `obj.bar = {"foo" : "Hello"}` but `i_bar` didn't notice the change. I guess that since no value was assigned at creation, javascript decided to treat it as a primitive, not an object, even after it was changed to an object.

Comment: Not exactly.  It treats it as `undefined`. `undefined++ === undefined`.   Setting `obj.var = {"foo", "Hello"}` will create an object which will be passed by reference.

Comment: Well, this is weird. I modified it so `_bar = {"foo" : "Hello"}` and `i_bar(){return _bar}`. If I do `obj.bar = {"foo" : "Bye"}`, `obj.bar.foo` will print "Bye", but `obj.i_bar().foo` will still print "Hello".